# Что исправить/дополнить в манифесте, чтобы приложение устанавливалось на смартфоне Sony Experia Z3 под Андроид 5.1.1

Tags: java, android

Везде устанавливается, а под Sony Experia Z3 (Андроид 5.1.1) нет.

Подскажите, что исправить в манифесте:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.listview" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:icon="@drawable/tt128"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/tt128"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".about">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Какая ошибка выводится при установке ? Какая версия ```Android``` установлена в ```build.gradle``` для модуля приложения(если проект в ```AndroidStudio```)?

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую указать хотя бы `versionCode`, `versionName`, `<uses-sdk>` `<supports-screen>`

Про AndroidManifest.xml можно здесь почитать: http://devcolibri.com/3010

Comment: Если проект в ```AndroidStudio``` то перечисленные вами параметры указываются в ```build.gradle``` и в ```AndroidManifest.xml``` могут не указываться.